# Communication between browser tabs, Javascript

Tags: javascript, tabs, communication

I'm designing this web-based production management software which includes customer, product and order databases. I'm trying to accomplish the following functionality.

When the user wants to create new order to the system, there should be two ways to do that.

1st way. User can first navigate to the "search customers"-page and when he finds the right one, he can click a button "Make new order for this customer" or something like that.

Then an "add order"-page opens with the information about the customer already in place.

At this page, if the user clicks a button "Add products", a "search for products"-page should open in a new tab.

Then the user could add products to the "add order"-page that is open in the background tab by clicking let's say "Add this product" button.

When the user closes the "search product"-page the products would be there waiting at the "add order"-page.

2nd route. User can go directly to the "search for products"-page and when he clicks the same "Add this product" button, a kind of a blank "add order"-page should open to the background tab with the newly added product information.

Then the user could again keep adding products until he's done.

How should I try to accomplish this kind off a two-way interaction between the "add order"-page and "search for products"-page which is dependent on the initiator? Should I use cookies, ajax or some kind of parent, child relation and messing with window.opener?

I have tried to achieve this the following way but it doesn't work.

```js
// code in the "search for products"-page

var productGB;
var destGB;

function JsTakeProductToOrder(product) {    // This is the function to be executed 
 if (window.opener) {                    // when user clicks "Add this product..."
  productGB = product;
  destGB = window.opener;
  JsDeliverProduct(); 
 }
 if (!window.opener) {
  productGB = product;
  if  (typeof destGB == 'undefined') {
   destGB = window.open("addOrder.php");
  }
  else {
   JsDeliverProduct();
  }
 }
}

/*The function JsDeliverProducts here just basically assings values to
variables in destGB like "destGB.productID = document.getElementById(productGB)..."
and then at the end executes destGB.addRow() which is on the "add order"-page

If the above function is executed with it not being opened by the "add order"-page.
The page gets opened and when its loaded (<body onload="JsPageLoaded[]">) the JsPageLoaded
function executes JsTakeProductToOrder() function on its opener being this page right here.

I might suck at explaining this but still.
*/

//  The relevant code in the "add order"-page

function JsPageLoaded() { // If the page has been opened by the "search for products"-page it menas
 if (window.opener) {  // that there is a product information to be collected.
  window.opener.JsTakeProductToOrder();
 }
}

function JsAddProduct () { // This function fires when "Add products" button is clicked and opens
 if (!window.opener) {  // the "search for products"-page if its not already open.
  if  (typeof search == 'undefined') {
   search = window.open("searchProducts.php");
   search.focus();
  }
 }
}

function JsAddRow() {
 alert(code+" "+title+" "+units+" "+netPrice+" "+vat);
 search.focus();
}
```

I hope that you've understood what I'm after. I have only just now started with web-programming but I have some experience with embedded systems and PLC:s.

Comment: You can use my sysend library that allow to send messages between open tabs https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#broadcasting-to-other-browsing-contexts would be perfect… except nobody is implementing it yet.